# Translating debian network configuration to gentoo

Tags: networking, debian, vps, openvz, gentoo

I just got rid off Debian on my VPS (OpenVZ) and installed Gentoo on it, however it is a plain Gentoo image without further configuration, i.e. no working network.

I'm not familiar with Debian and coulnd't figure out how to get the network set up, these are the debian network files

`/etc/network/interfaces`:

> auto venet0
>   iface venet0 inet manual
>
> > up ifconfig venet0 up
> >        up ifconfig venet0 127.0.0.2
> >        up route add default dev venet0
> >        down route del default dev venet0
> >        down ifconfig venet0 down
>
> iface venet0 inet6 manual
>
> > up ifconfig venet0 add ipv6addr/128
> >        down ifconfig venet0 del ipv6addr/128
> >        up route -A inet6 add default dev venet0
> >        down route -A inet6 del default dev venet0
>
> auto venet0:0
>   iface venet0:0 inet static
>
> > address external_ip
> >        netmask 255.255.255.255
>
> auto venet0:1
>   iface venet0:1 inet static
>
> > address internal_ip
> >     netmask 255.255.255.255

Please note that **external_ip**, **internal_ip** and **ipv6addr** are placeholders. I copied the `/etc/resolv.conf`, know the **gateway_ip** and also have another ouput of ifconfig, if necessary.

This is what I came up with, `/etc/conf.d/net`:

> config_venet0="127.0.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.255 brd 0.0.0.0"
>   config_venet0:0="external_ip netmask 255.255.255.255 brd 0.0.0.0"
>   route_venet0:0="default via gateway_ip"
>   config_venet0:1="internal_ip netmask 255.255.255.255 brd 0.0.0.0"

Broadcast IP is taken from ifconfig debian output - however it doesn't work.

A symbolic link `net.venet0:0 -> net.lo` in `/etc/init.d/` was created and I added `net.venet0:0` to the boot runlevel.

Comment: So, you went from one distro you don't understand to another distro you don't understand.  Have you considered perhaps using a distro you *do* understand?

Comment: You are hell of a nice guy.

Comment: Sometimes honesty has its purpose. He's right (especially with your Gentoo choice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if you want to get the network with a buyvm/frantech VPS and the Sabayon testing image working, here is how you do it:

1. copy the `/etc/resolv.conf` from debian/whatever standard OS is installed and working
2. `/etc/conf.d/net`:

   > config_venet0="127.0.0.2/32 **external_ip**/32 **internal_ip**/32 **ipv6addr**/128"
   >   routes_venet0="default via **gateway_ip**"
   >   modules="iproute2"
3. `ln -s /etc/init.d/net.lo /etc/init.d/net.venet0`
4. `emerge -n iproute2`
5. `rc-update add net.venet0 default`

Don't forget to start sshd and everything should be working. The resolf.conf is somehow deleted every boot (this must be the hosters doing).

While Debian network configuration supports the old ifconfig method of alias IPs, you don't need that on newer systems.